# Python files created do not save as python file

Tags: python, image, file, editor, python-idle

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwR0ium7uufRWnhXWWNFcVJ3S2c/edit?usp=sharing

The files that are blank and say "Credit Card Balance" and "mine" are the files which I created by opening up a new document in IDLE and creating a file. The ones with the little pictures and say ps2_newton are programs which I downloaded off of the internet. I can't open my files which I created like they are regular programs and have to open them under notepad to see the code. Why is this? How can I change my files to look and act like the ones I downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

The files you downloaded have an extension of ".py", which tells Windows to open them with the Python launcher, while the ones you created have no extension, or an extension of ".txt", which tells Windows to open them in Notepad.

Since ".py" and ".txt" are both "known extensions", and you have Explorer configured to hide known extensions (which I believe is the default in all versions of Windows), it doesn't show them to you. However, you can see the difference in the icons.

You can configure Explorer to show all extensions, but this site is not the place to ask about that—try [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Meanwhile, when you save your scripts, make sure you save them with a `.py` extension (or, if they're Tkinter or other GUI apps, with a `.pyw` extension).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I just deleted all of the é's and á's etc. And it worked! So try that IF it is an .py file. Otherwise I understand if it does not work becouse it isn't a python file. You change that by doing this: Save as. Just simply type .py after the file name.

PS Sorry for my bad english...